# Weird Question regarding C integer type and printf() specifier

Tags: c, integer

Alright i know this question might some weird , but still i wanted to demystify it.

1.)an `int` type in C can stores number in the range of -2147483648 to 2147483647.

2.)If we append an `unsigned` it front of it , the range would become 0 to 2147483647.

3.)The thing is , why do we even bother to use the keyword `unsigned` when the code below could actually works.

**The Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 2147483650;

    printf("%u\n" , num);

    return 0;
}
```

4.)As you see , i can still print out the integer as unsigned type if I use the `%u` specifier and it will print me the value `2147483650`.

5.)Even if I create another integer type with value `50` and sum it up with `num` , although it's overflow but yet I still can  print out the correct sum value by using `%u` specifier.So why `unsigned` keyword is still a necessity??

Thanks for spending time reading my question.

Comment: Apart from undefined behavior, printing is far from the only meaningful operation on (`unsigned`) integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering only Q3, "Why do we bother to use unsigned", consider this program fragment:

```
int main(void) {

  int num = MAX_INT;
  num += 50;

  printf("%u\n", num); /* Yes, this *might* print what you want */

  /* But this "if" almost certainly won't do what you want. */
  if(num > 0) {
    printf("Big numbers are big\n");
  } else {
    printf("Big numbers are small\n");
  }
}
```

We use "unsigned" because `unsigned int` behaves differently from `int`. There are more interesting behaviors than just how `printf` works.

Comment: A popular use for unsigned integers is with bits.  Signed integers behave differently when shifted or rotated by a number of bits than unsigned integers.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, this is true only on certain platforms (where an `int` is 32-bit, 2's-complement).
2. No, in that case the range would be 0 to 4294967295.
3. That code exhibits *undefined behaviour*.
4. See 3.
5. See 2. and 3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrong. The range is INT_MIN (which in 2 completment systems usually is -INT_MAX+1) to INT_MAX; INT_MAX and INT_MIN depends on the compiler, architecture, etc.
2. Wrong. The range is 0 to UINT_MAX which is usually INT_MAX*2 + 1
3. Unsigned integers have a different behaviour regarding overflow and semantics. In 2 complement there's one value undefined for signed integers (that is if only the uppermost bit is set, the rest zero), that has somewhat a double meaning. Unsigned integers can make use of the full range of bit patterns.
4. Here's an exercise: On a 32 bit machine compare the output of printf("%d %u", 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff);
5. Because unsigned integers behave differently than signed ones.

Comment: @Oli: Right you are, yet again.

Comment: Still wrong: ignoring overflows it is `-INT_MAX - 1` or `-(INT_MAX + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly the result of assigning an out-of-range number is implementation-defined - it doesn't have to give the value that will "work" when printed with the `%u` format specifier.  But to really answer your question, consider this modification to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 2147483650;
    unsigned num2 = 2147483650;

    num /= 2;
    num2 /= 2;

    printf("%u, %u\n" , num, num2);

    return 0;
}
```

(If 2147483650 is out of range of `int` on your platform, but within the range of `unsigned`, then you will only get the correct answer of 1073741825 using the `unsigned` type).